# How can I check what version of macOS I was using in the past?

Tags: macos

I need to find what version on macOS was being used on my macbook back in December, or preferably, on any given date. Is there way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

Brief details of all software installations and updates (macOS and applications) are kept by macOS and can be displayed with System Information.  To get to this:

1. Option-click on the Apple at top left;
2. Choose System Information (the first item in the drop down);
3. The System Information app will open;
4. In the sidebar choose Software > Installations.

This displays a one line for every software installation.

As an example, I sorted by date and scrolled to 31-Dec-21. I then scrolled back in time to find that I installed macOS 12.1 on 14-Dec-21.

[image: Sytem Information]

Two things to note:

1. This only lists installations since you last did a clean install.
2. There is some duplication in macOS entries. I think this is because downloads of macOS installer packages get logged as well as their installation.

**Edit (due to @lhf)**:

The Terminal command, equivalent to using System Information is:

`system_profiler SPInstallHistoryDataType`

For a different answer use this Terminal command:

`softwareupdate --history | grep macOS`

which on my iMac, produces:

```
macOS 11.1                                         11.1       15/12/2020, 09:11:28
macOS Big Sur 11.2 Update                          11.2       02/02/2021, 09:44:45
macOS Big Sur                                      11.2.1     12/02/2021, 10:24:34
macOS Big Sur 11.2.2                               11.2.2     05/03/2021, 12:52:50
macOS Big Sur 11.2.3                               11.2.3     22/03/2021, 12:44:55
macOS 11.3                                         11.3       27/04/2021, 09:54:13
macOS Big Sur 11.3.1                               11.3.1     05/05/2021, 15:56:53
macOS Big Sur 11.4                                 11.4       25/05/2021, 10:47:17
macOS 11.5                                         11.5       22/07/2021, 13:03:07
macOS Big Sur 11.5.1                               11.5.1     27/07/2021, 12:54:40
macOS 11.5.2                                       11.5.2     15/08/2021, 14:30:43
macOS 11.6                                         11.6       19/09/2021, 08:55:54
macOS 12.0.1                                       12.0.1     30/10/2021, 13:10:03
macOS 12.1                                         12.1       14/12/2021, 11:55:48
macOS 12.2                                         12.2       27/01/2022, 13:33:51
macOS Monterey 12.2.1                              12.2.1     12/02/2022, 09:37:04
macOS 12.3                                         12.3       16/03/2022, 15:56:56
macOS 12.3.1                                       12.3.1     01/04/2022, 10:04:17
macOS 12.4                                         12.4       17/05/2022, 13:50:48
```

This Terminal command is restricted to updates from macOS 11 onwards, but correctly shows only real installed updates and doesn't include downloads.

Comment: Also `zgrep -w Installed /var/log/install.log* | grep macOS`

Comment: @lhf I didn't know that one. But it misses a lot on my Macs, and only specifies by pretty name (e.g. Monterey) and not version number.

Comment: The command line equivalent of your solution is `system_profiler SPInstallHistoryDataType`.

Comment: I get `Installed "macOS Catalina" (10.15.7)` for instance. But I'm running Catalina.

Comment: Try also `softwareupdate --his | grep macOS`.

Comment: @lhf That is much more precise than my System Information answer as it shows just real installations.  I will edit my answer.